# tinyMCE how to unselect selected area

Tags: tinymce-4, programmatically-created, unselect

Im working with tinyMCE 4.x and would like to remove ANY set format in the whole editor text programmatically. It just should do what the removeFormat command does. So far I came:

```
tinymce.execCommand('selectAll', true, 'texteditor');
tinymce.execCommand('RemoveFormat', true, 'texteditor');
```

The removeFormat works only on preselected text so I do a 'SelectAll' before RemoveFormat. That works fine but all stays selected after RemoveFormat. So the question is: Is there a way to remove any format without selecting all before? If no, how do I unselect previously selected text? (I tried to set focus on texteditor after, but selection remains). Im sure there is a simple way just couldn't find it in the net.

Answer (score 6):

I guess I found an answer. After using RemoveFormat you can add this line:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.selection.collapse();
```